# How to change IP address of single Openstack deployment

Tags: controller, ip, openstack, openstack-nova, horizon

I would like to know is it possible to change IP address of Openstack deployed on single server (all-in-one), I would like to avoid from deployed it again based on new IP address. If it can be done, please advise which part should I change. Thank you for your help and advise.

My server NIC1 is connected to network 192.168.0.10/24. Deployment of Openstack is using 192.168.0.10 as the IP address, my horizon browser access also is via 192.168.0.10.

Now I want to connect the server NIC1 to network 172.16.100.90/24. I know that horizon IP should be change to 172.16.100.90 and for sure that's not the only component that I need to change. Thus, what other component that I should change/update with the new IP and how it can be done.

Or shall I just change/update IP pointing to myosp1 ---->etc/hosts only?

[image]

[Change Openstack IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733186/single-instance-openstack-ip-network-configuration)

Comment: What IP address do you mean? You can change the individual endpoints by using `openstack endpoint set <endpoint>`.

Comment: Hi BakaKuna, I have updated my question. Hope you can advise further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think if all ip settings in openstack service config(like nova.conf, cinder.conf, neutron.conf, etc.), you use domain name (myosp1), maybe you just only to modify the /etc/hosts file.

But if you wrote ip in openstack service config, you need to change all files, included using command to modify keystone endpoint.

Comment: Hi sir....thanks for your response and advise. Unfortunately the config file is based on IP.